# Really weird results for a logistic model - is it due to high frequency of one value on response variable?

Tags: logistic, generalized-linear-model, regression-coefficients, logit, separation

I am trying to test whether experimental group (a vs b) influences the probability of some binary outcome, but the model results are strange.

The code I'm using:

```
model<-glm(data$outcome ~ data$condition, family=binomial(logit))
```

The parameter estimate for the intercept is 11.11, and the estimate for the condition variable is -18.91, p = .99. These values don't make any sense to me. For example, the intercept should represent the log-odds of a specific outcome, and I know that the frequency of that outcome is high (111/120) so the intercept should be highly significant.

Is it possible that this is not working because the one outcome is so frequent relative to the other? If not, any other idea about what is going wrong here? I ran the same model with a different outcome variable and the results were interpretable and the only difference I can find is that the relative frequency of the two outcomes is more balanced.

Comment: http://math.yorku.ca/Who/Faculty/Monette/S-news/0027.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your diagnosis is correct. You probably have what is called separation where for one level of your predictor only one outcome occurs. Also search for Hauck-Donner effect.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right. I reran the model with another predictor where for both levels both outcomes occurred and the problem disappeared.